# Issues during server migration

Tags: php, migration

What are the probable bugs that could occur during server migration ? I am a tester and I need to test a site after server migration, so which are the key areas that I need to focus while testing ?

Comment: What are you migrating exactly? A LAMP configuration? With one or more web applications? Which ones? From one version to another?... Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of quick points I think of:

1. Ensure that your configuration file has been updated. If it is not, your site will no longer work or your images may not appear etc.
2. If any specific parts of your site use a specific component (e.g. ImageMagick or GD or cURL), make sure those pages are tested again. You should also check if all the required components are installed.
3. Test by adding dummy entries using your site forms and then deleting them afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Well best thing is to create some scenarios with a tool like [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) ,or [badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/)
on the old server and then to migrate the scenarios on the new one...